# Prime numbers in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to determine the prime numbers in an array:

What am i doing wrong in the main method?

What should i change?

Is tthe algorithm even good?

Please help me out! I just started learning java and i really want to know more and more things! :D

```
package prime;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class primeClass {

private static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arr=new int[100];
    int n;
    input=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=input.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        arr[i]=input.nextInt();
        isPrime(arr[i]);
    }

}
public static void isPrime(int[] arr){
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        if(isPrimeNum(arr[i])){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
}

public static boolean isPrimeNum(int n){
    int d=0;
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
        if(n%j==0)
            d++;
    if(d==2)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Assuming your code actually works, this sort of question is better-suited to [codereview.SE].

Comment: Is anything wrong with your code? or do you simply need to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if everything else is ok, but I'd change `isPrimeNum` like this.-

```
public static boolean isPrimeNum(int n) {
    for(int j = 2; j < n; j++) {
        if(n % j == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Whenever you find a `j` greater than `1` and less than `n` which can divide `n` without giving a remainder, you can say `n` is not prime.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using an array at all? I don't see any point to having it.

`n%1` is always 0 so you can skip the number `0`, also you can skip the number `n` as `n%n` is always 0 too.

Your isPrimeNum can return true as soon as it find a match which is >=2 and < n. A much shorter search is

This does half the checks after 2

```
if (n % 2 == 0) return false; // check is even
for(int j = 3, m = (int) Math.sqrt(n); j <= m; j += 2) // skip all the even.
    if(n % j == 0)
       return false;
return true;
```

To optimise this further you can do the following.  This does 1/3rd the checks after 3.

```
if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) return false; // check is even + 3x
for(int j = 5, m = (int) Math.sqrt(n); j <= m; j += 6) { // skip even + 3x
    if(n % j == 0)
       return false;
    if(n % (j + 2) == 0)
       return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: What do you use m for?

Comment: @JohannesH. Good point, fixed the code.

Comment: Skipping every 2nd number isn't necessary BTW, if 2 divided n, you already returned.

Comment: @JohannesH. It is not necessary, just twice as fast as it checks half the numbers. Also, if you don't cache the result of sqrt(), there is no guarantee the JIT will and it is relatively expensive.

Comment: Oh, yeah, never mind. You're right of course.

Comment: @JohannesH. It's just my obsession. That's why I got the first gold badge for `[performance]` and I am the sort of person that thinks that is a good thing ;)

Comment: I actually though of that improvement, too, but then for some reason I can no longer see decided that it isn't necessary. Edited my answer below (which is basically the same you did with a little more explanation) to include that, too.

Comment: @JohannesH. You can optimise it further by groups of 6 (to skip multiple of 3) or 30 (skip multiples of 5 as well) but it gets increasingly complicated.  The skipping evens trick only adds one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no need to count j to n. It is sufficient to count until you reach sqrt(n).
Second, it is sufficient to start j at 2. Every number can be divided by 1, so there is no point in checking that.
Third, you should not count all numbers that can divide n, but simply stop at the first one you find.
Last but not least: if 2 didn't divide n, no even number will, so you can skip those. (Thanks @PeterLawrey)

Code would now be:

```
for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(n); j+=2) {
    if (n%j) return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my points concerning the code:

- In the `main` method you start the `for`-loop at index position 1. The first index position in an array is 0.
- Again the `for`-loop in the main method:  The line`isPrime(arr[i]);` should give you a compile error as the method expects an array and not an int.
- Why do not you split up your task into two? Task one consists of reading the user input into an array and task two determines the prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your main method to look like this, with isPrime outside the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arr=new int[100];
    int n;
    input=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=input.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        arr[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
    primeClass.isPrime(arr);
}
```